# Force that an axle exerts on wheel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Consider a wheel attached to an axle.

Since the torque on both must be the same:

$$F_wR_w=F_aR_a$$
$$F_w < F_a$$

because the radius of the wheel is greater than radius of the axle.

My question is: What horizontal force does the axle exert on the wheel?

My ideas: the total force exerted on the system must be the force of the axle into the wheel minus the force of the wheel into the ground because if you draw the free body diagram you can see the negative component hence:

$$F_{tot} = F_{aw}-F_{wg}$$
$$F_{aw}= F_{tot} + F_{wg}$$

Is this correct?

[image]

Is the direction of the Horizontal force of the wheel on the ground "wg" correct?

Comment: Torque and force have different dimensions (units of N⋅m vs. N), so you can't add them. Your equation is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: sorrry I mean tangetial force of the wheel with the ground + F total in the free body diagram seems like it is the horizontal force of the axle on the wheel

Comment: Didn't you promise a diagram?

Comment: Already post the diagram I am statring to think that the horizontal force of the wheel into the ground must be in the forward direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a free-body diagram of the wheel in some general state. The contact normal force $N$ is accompanied by a tractive force $F$ as well as the torque $\tau$ from the axle.

[image: fig1]

and here is the free-body diagram of the axle

[image: fig2]

with equal and opposite forces acting on it, in addition to the weight $W$ that the axle bears. Also, note the motor torque $\tau_E$ applied that generates the torque $\tau$ transmitted to the wheel.

I am ignoring the mass of the wheel since the *net* force along the direction of motion is zero.

The force $N$ is such as for the wheel not to go into the ground under the influence of the weight on the axle.

The force $F$ is generated from the torque $\tau = F r$ in order to keep the wheel from slipping.

The total force acting on the axle is the vector sum of the two forces

$$ F_{\rm axle} = \sqrt{ N^2 + F^2} $$

as both torque and weight contribute to the loading.

Comment: thats the force that the wheel exerts on the axle?

Comment: @VOZESTOICA - yes